# How to transfer multiple rows output to another php file to process data?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<form name="myForm" action="doControlAcc.php"  method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="20" class="display" id="acc" width="200">
            <thead>
            <tr><h2>Accessories summary</h2></tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Currently - Ex Factory</th>
                <th>Minimum Required Stock</th>
                <th>Update by</th>
                <th>Last update</th>
                <th>Re-Stock Amount</th>
                <th>Stock Out</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <?php
               $accessories = array()
               $query  = "SELECT description, current_stock, min_required_stock, c_ex_factory, last_update from Accessories”;

                $result= mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));      
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                    $order = $row['c_ex_factory'] - $row['min_required_stock'];
                    if ($order < 0){
                        $order = $row['min_required_stock']-$row['c_ex_factory'];
                        $color = "#FF0000";
                    }else{
                        $order = 0;
                        $color = "#00FF00";
                    }



                ?>
            <tr>
                <td name="accessories[]" id="accessories"   value=”<?php echo $row['description'] ?>” <?php echo in_array($row['description', $ accessories) > <?php echo $row['description']; ?> </td>
                <td align="center" name="accessories[]"  id="accessories"   value=”<?php echo $row[''c_ex_factory '] ?>” <?php echo in_array($row[''c_ex_factory ', $ accessories) > <?php echo $row['c_ex_factory']; ?> </td>
                <td align="center" name="accessories[]"  id="accessories"   value=”<?php echo $row[''min_required_stock '] ?>” <?php echo in_array($row[''min_required_stock ', $ accessories) > <?php echo $row['min_required_stock']; ?> </td>
                <td align="center" name="accessories[]"  id="accessories"   value=”<?php echo $row[' name '] ?>” <?php echo in_array($row[' name ', $ accessories) > <?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
                <td align="center" name="accessories[]"id="accessories"   value=”<?php echo $row['description'] ?>” <?php echo in_array($row['description', $ accessories) > <?php echo $row['up_when']; ?> </td>
                <td align="center" name="accessories[]"  bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>" id="accessories" <?php echo in_array($row[' re_stock ', $ accessories) > <input type="text" size="5" name="re_stock" value=" <?php echo $order ?>"/> </td>
                <td align="center" name="accessories[]"id="accessories"   <?php echo in_array($row[' out_stock ', $ accessories) > <input type="text" size="5" name="out_stock" value ="0"/></td>                    
            </tr>

                <?php

                }

                ?>

               <tr>
                   <td> </td> 
                   <td>                         </td> 
                   <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> 
                <td><button  data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Send order</button></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </form>
```

Hello,
I'm new to web programming.
The code above will fetch the data from database to create a table in PHP, then it will take the user inputs for stock-out and restock and send those to doControlAcc.php file. 
The problem I'm facing is I need to create multiple input lines so that users can enter stock-out and re-stock for different products. And I don't know how to pass these multiple lines to doControlAcc.php file after the form is filled. (i.e how can I access accessories array in doControlAcc.php?).

THank you for your help.

Comment: Do not use `”`, but use `"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but you can always use session variables. I can't quite understand the program you are writing, so I can't say whether or not sessions would be safe enough, but if you wanted to use sessions, do something like this:

At the beginning of your file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

And later, when the variable is all set:

```
$_SESSION['accessories'] = $accessories;
```

To access it in another code file, you must start the session as shown above in each code file. Then, just do this;

```
$accessories = $_SESSION['accessories'];
```